# Django's ModelForm - where is the list of Meta options?

Tags: django, django-admin

In the Django documentation, where is the definitive list of `Meta` options for `django.forms.models.ModelForm`?  (e.g., `model`, `exclude`, `fields`, `widgets`)  I'm looking for the equivalent of [Model Meta Options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/).

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: Thanks @catherine.  I saw that page, but the ModelForm Meta options are scattered throughout the page, rather than being listed like the Meta options in the Model Meta Options page does.  But maybe that's the only documentation for them that exists?

Comment: Maybe we can request for that in Django

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Had this question myself today. For completeness, here is the documentation that currently exists:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelforms-overriding-default-fields

And an excerpt from [django/forms/models.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.1/django/forms/models.py#L195):

```
class ModelFormOptions:
    def __init__(self, options=None):
        self.model = getattr(options, 'model', None)
        self.fields = getattr(options, 'fields', None)
        self.exclude = getattr(options, 'exclude', None)
        self.widgets = getattr(options, 'widgets', None)
        self.localized_fields = getattr(options, 'localized_fields', None)
        self.labels = getattr(options, 'labels', None)
        self.help_texts = getattr(options, 'help_texts', None)
        self.error_messages = getattr(options, 'error_messages', None)
        self.field_classes = getattr(options, 'field_classes', None)
```

From that list, I searched for each option on the docs page to find what I needed. Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Note that `labels`, `help_texts` and `error_messages` were added in Django 1.6

Comment: what do I pass to `ModelFormOptions` as `options`?

Comment: @SashkoLykhenko you dont "pass" anything to `ModelFormOptions` you define an inner `Meta` class inside your form class and define these  "options" as its attributes. then behind the scenes when you create an instance of your form, django creates an instance of your meta class and passes it as "options" to the `ModelFormOptions` class