# How to change default values on label, required message and invalid message Django modelForm

Tags: django

I have the following code, It works properly but the issue is that i want to be able to change the message that shows This Field is Required, or when it says this is invalid I know there is a way to add this but the many that i've tried before did not work. this way works but i'm not able to modify the messages.

```
from django import forms
from models import user


class loginForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = user
        fields = ('username', 'password',)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [custom error messages with Model Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436712/custom-error-messages-with-model-form)

Comment: the answer is from django import forms
from user.models import user


class loginForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = user
        fields = ('username',)

        error_messages = {
            'username': {
                'required': ('Please enter username'),
            },

        }

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer that worked for me in this case. Hope helps anyone who has this issue also.

```
from django import forms 
from user.models import user 

class loginForm(forms.ModelForm): 

    class Meta: 
          model = user 
          fields = ('username') 

          error_messages = { 
              'username': { 
                  'required': ('Please enter username'), 
              }, 
          }
```