# How to prevent rendering error messages in input field value in Django template?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

The required field error in my form are shown in input field value attribute:

Django `forms.py`

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    pic = forms.ImageField(required=False, error_messages = {'invalid':_("Image files only")}, widget=forms.FileInput)

    #http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436712/custom-error-messages-with-model-form
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('pic', 'mobile', 'bio', 'location', 'website')
        widgets = {
            "mobile" : TextInput(attrs={"class" : "mobile"}),
            "bio" : Textarea(attrs={"class" : "bio", 'cols': 50, 'rows': 5}),
        }

        error_messages = {
            'mobile': {
                'required': _("Please enter your mobile number."),
            },
            'bio': {
                'required': _("Please enter your bio."),
            },
            'location': {
                'required': _("Please enter location."),
            },
            'website': {
                'required': _("Please enter your website."),
            },
        }

        help_texts = {
            'mobile': _('Fill your active mobile numbers.'),
        }

        labels = {
            "pic": _("Photo"),
            "mobile": _("Mobile"),
            "bio": _("bio"),
        }

    def is_valid(self):
        form = super(ProfileForm, self).is_valid()
        for f, error in self.errors.iteritems():
            if f != '__all__':
                self.fields[f].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'error', 'value': removetags(error, 'ul li')})
        return form
```

Django `Template`:

```
<h2>Edit Profile</h2>
<form action="/edit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >{% csrf_token %}
    <p class='profile_p'>{{ profile_form.pic.label_tag }}
        <span class='pic_upload_btn'>Upload Profile Picture</span>
        {{ profile_form.html_name }}
        {% if pic %}
            <img src='{{STATIC_URL}}images/{{ pic.pic }}' width='100' height='100' />
        {% endif %}
        {{ profile_form.pic }}
    </p>
    <p>{{ profile_form.mobile.label_tag }}
    {{ profile_form.mobile }}
    {{ profile_form.mobile.help_text }}
    <span>{{ profile_form.mobile.errors }}</span>
    </p>
    <p>{{ profile_form.bio.label_tag }}
    {{ profile_form.bio }}
    </p>
    <p>{{ profile_form.location.label_tag }}
    {{ profile_form.location }}
    {{ profile_form.location.errors }}
    </p>
    <p>{{ profile_form.website.label_tag }}
    {{ profile_form.website }}
    {{ profile_form.website.errors }}
    </p>
    <input type="submit" id="btnSignUp" value="Update">
</form>
```

Html
If mobile field is kept empty and form is submitted. It displays error message inside input field with red color:

```
<input id="id_mobile" class="error" type="text" value="Please enter your mobile number." name="mobile">
```

[image]
How can I prevent the errors so they do not appear in input field?

Comment: any help appreciated?

Comment: Probably in that case you will have to render the element by yourself and not through django, i.e use `<input id="id_mobile" name="mobile">` and not `{{profile_form.mobile}}`.

Comment: Add your form's code to the question. By default this shouldn't happen.

Comment: @schillingt question is updated.

Comment: Sorry, I meant your forms.py code.

Answer (score 1):

Solved myself.

The above error gets fixed by commenting the following code in forms.py :

```
 def is_valid(self):

    form = super(ProfileForm, self).is_valid()
    for f, error in self.errors.iteritems():
        if f != '__all__':
            self.fields[f].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'error', 'value': removetags(error, 'ul li')})
    return form
```

thank you all for help.