# Changing Error Message in Django

Tags: django

I want to change the error message but I couldnt I tried the methods below. The didn't work for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8977228/6584242

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3437158/6584242

## My Model

```
class Contact(models.Model):
isim = models.CharField(max_length =120, blank =False, null =True,error_messages={'required': 'Bu alan doldurulmalidir'})
soyad = models.CharField(max_length =120, blank =False, null =True,default='Burasi doldurulmalidir',error_messages={'required': 'Bu alan doldurulmalidir'})
kurum = models.CharField(max_length =120, blank =False, null =False,default='Burasi doldurulmalidir',error_messages={'required': 'Bu alan doldurulmalidir'})
bolum = models.CharField(max_length =120, blank =False, null =False,default='Burasi doldurulmalidir',error_messages={'required': 'Bu alan doldurulmalidir'})
....
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.user)
```

## My Forms

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Contact
    fields = ['unvan','isim','soyad','kurum',"bolum","gorev", "uzmanlik","adres","posta_kodu","sehir","ulke","is_tel","ev_tel","fax_no","cep_tel"]
    field_args = {
        "isim" : {
            "error_messages" : {
                "required" : "Please let us know what to call you!"
            }
        }
    }
```

Where do I make wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no such thing as `field_args`; that answerer has written a custom extension to do that. You should use the syntax shown in the other answer.

Comment: Yes I know it I just wrote this way because both of answers doesn't work for me.