# Django: Override form.errors messages on UserCreationForm

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to override (add languages) the messages of form.errors. I've tried this:

**forms.py**

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.error_messages['duplicate_username'] = 'some message'
```

After the form is submitted, it's not saved because username are unique and the error is displayed on the template. I'd like to make the same with the password but I can't find out the errors' key for each password validation. Can you provide me it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Custom Error Messages with Model Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436712/create-custom-error-messages-with-model-forms)

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I’m using UserCreationForm. Can I edit this form like that?

Comment: But I still need the keys (what I’m asking for)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set [**`error_messages`**--(Django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#error-messages) attribute in Meta class as,

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
        error_messages = {
            'username': {
                'unique': 'Your Custom Error Message here !!!',
            },
        }
```

---

If you want to override the *password mismatch* error message, override the **`error_messages`** attribute in the form class (not in the `Meta` class) as below,

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': "Your Password Mismatch For 'UserCreationForm' class",
    }
    # other code
```

Comment: Do you have the docs of password validation errors? I’m trying to override them

Comment: how can I override the password's help text? Like "this password is too short, this password is too common, etc "

Comment: Please ask a different question since the OP issue has been solved. Apart from that, it would be a great start if you go through the official Django doc

Comment: I’ve been looking for that but I just founded information for the version 1.8 or 2.0

Comment: official doc has the information of Django 1.8+ versions.