# In python, what the underline parameter mean in function

Tags: python

For example, I read a code:

```
def parse_doc(self, _, doc):
```

What does the underline "_" mean?

Answer (score 45):

It usually is a place holder for a variable we don't care about. For instance if you have a `for`-loop and you don't care about the value of the index, you can do something like

```
for _ in xrange(10):
   print "hello World." # just want the message 10 times, no need for index val
```

another example, if a function returns a tuple and you don't care about one of the values you could use `_` to make this explicit. E.g.,

```
val, _ = funky_func() # "ignore" one of the return values
```

---

***Aside***

Unrelated to the use of `'_'` in OP's question, but still neat/useful. In the Python shell, `'_'` will contain the result of the last operation. E.g.,

```
>>> 55+4
59
>>> _
59
>>> 3 * _
177
>>>
```

Comment: _("sometext") usually indicates text to be translated  (again unrelated to OP's Q)

Comment: @xueliangliu If this answered your question about the meaning of `'_'` please consider [accepting this answer by clicking the checkmark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) next to the answer. It will reward both of us with some rep points and mark this problem as solved.

Answer (score 6):

Like `doc` it's a variable name. Usually naming a variable `_` indicates that it won't be used.

Comment: or _("something")  indicates text to be localized(translated)  ... its also a magic variable that holds the last result when used in the python shell ...

Answer (score 4):

`_` is a valid variable name in python. But it is mostly used in [i18n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964244/django-meaning-of-leading-underscore-in-list-of-tuples-used-to-define-choice-fi), so it's better to not to use it for other purposes.