# How to translate Django messages depending on the language selected

Tags: django, django-messages

Hello I have a multy lingual project in Django.
I have done the translations with `USE_I18N`.

Everything works fine in the templates  with the

`{%  trans 'hello world'  %}`

but how should I process the messages?

when I send

`messages.warning(request, "Невалиден имеил или парола")`

I want it to be translated in **english** if the language selected is **english**

Comment: Use `_("Невалиден имеил или парола")` instead, this is (more or less) the equialent of `{% trans '...' %}`.

Comment: See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext

Comment: when i use `_`  in front of the messages says unresolved reference

Comment: of course, you first need to `import` it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2964256/67579

Comment: solved it guys thanks for the references